# Why is needed android support v4 and v7 library?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Why is needed android support version 4 and version 7 library?
Please help me friends

```
import android.support.v4
import android.support.v7
```

I can these support library in gingerbread API Android level 10.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher. It includes the largest set of APIs compared to the other libraries, including support for application components, user interface features, accessibility, data handling, network connectivity, and programming utilities.

see this links

[link1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

[link2](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: Is to possible android apis level 10 actionbar or other?